# Significant slowdown when adding threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I've been working on making a model for the game Monopoly in C++.  My model works and is reasonably fast, however my advisor wants me to add multithreading to speed it up.

My system is Linux with gcc 4.8.2; I have an AMD FX 8350 with 8 cores + 16GB memory.  I also notice comparable results on my MacBook with Clang 6 and a Core i5 with 2 cores + HT.

The applicable function is:

```
int playSet(const int* basePlayer, int numberOfGames)
{
    int num1won = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGames; i++)
    {
        Player player1(basePlayer);

        Player* opponent = generateRandomPlayer(2);

        // Let's play!
        std::vector<Player*> players = {&player1, opponent};

        Game currentGame(players, NUMBER_OF_TURNS);

        int winner = currentGame.play().winner;

        if (1 == winner)
        {
            num1won++;
        }

        delete opponent;
}
```

`basePlayer` is an array which contains parameters for the player.

I first tried using `std::async` and `std::futures` (with `std::launch::async`) from C++11.  In my main I create a vector of `std::future`s and add to it with `futures.push_back(std::async(&playSet, basePlayer, numberOfGames / procs));`

Running 100,000 games with this setup with no threading enabled (i.e. those lines commented out and just calling the function) takes 208.76 seconds (according to time), 208.32s user and 0.19s is sys time. Running the same number of games with 8 threads gives me 208.53s, 207.73s user and 0.42s sys time.  Not at all the speedup my advisor is expecting (or I was hoping for).

Then I heard about OpenMP, and decided to give it a shot.  I left the C++11 threading stuff commented out and added the `#pragma omp parallel for` statement inside the function.

I again ran 100,000 games like this and it took 642.63s real, 714.18s user and a whopping 3228.62s of sys time (with OpenMP enabled).

I've run Valgrind/Helgrind, I've debugged it as much as I can think of, and everything checks out.  Is it reasonable to assume that the actual game playing takes so much [time to allocate memory/thrashes the cache/some other explanation]?  Is there anything that I can try without having to ask anybody to dive through a few thousand lines of game code?  I know it's a broad question, but I've been pulling my hair out for a couple months now without any luck on this.

Let me know if you need any more information to help.

`play` is the main method for the game, essentially.  I believe it is CPU bound.

I didn't specify `OMP_NUM_THREADS`, so I'd assume it went with a default of 8.  I manually set it to 8 and the time is the same.

[Here's a Pastebin from a Massif report](http://pastebin.com/KsNjmPcc) - as far as I can tell, there's not that much memory usage.

As far as setup time vs time spent in `play`, 0.178161s are spent total in setup for all games played and 87.0686s are spent in `play`.

Comment: We need to know what the code is actually doing. What does `play` do? Is it purely CPU-bound? Does it manipulate any shared structures?

Comment: what'st the value of OMP_NUM_THREADS ?

Comment: I updated my post.
@DavidSchwartz `play` does a lot, but it _should_ be CPU-bound.  @Kam it's at the default of 8.

Comment: One thing I'd try would be to create an alternate `play` which is *definitely* purely CPU bound, to try to tie down the locality of the problem.

Comment: I suggest you add a label of multithread

Comment: One thing I would do, is work out what percentage of that time is spent in buildup/teardown and how much is actually spent play()ing. Get the time just before and just after calling play() and see how it compares to the overall run time. If it's only a small fraction, then you might want to pre-allocate all your objects, and try again

Comment: `NUMBER_OF_TURNS` is how many, exactly? Try a large number.

Comment: How much memory do you have on your machine, what is your RAM usage during the time your program is running? Want to be sure of CPU-bound and that you're not somehow ending up with tons and tons of memory use so that you are paging.

Comment: `time` shows three values, you are only telling about two.

Comment: @AndyG it was 1000, upped it to 100,000 with essentially no difference - it's a turn cutoff and not an absolute number of turns to play.  I added RAM (16GB) and a Massif report (not a ton of RAM usage) to my post.

Comment: @n.m. sorry about that! I added the user time as well.

Comment: Is it only me who doesn't see where multithreading takes in place?

Comment: @Zaibis `#pragma omp parallel for`

Comment: High kernel time suggests either a lot of page faults, or unhealthy, unreasonable locking going on. I would guess it's not page faults since 16GB should be plenty for 8 games of Monopoly (unless the code seriously leaks) and besides it worked "fine" with C++ threading (although none faster). About `std::future` note that there is no strict requirement or guarantee that anything actually runs asynchronously. It could, in theory, run the code when you retrieve the result.

Comment: @AndyG `OpenMP` is not multi-threading, it's multi-processing. But I've already found out the answer: `std::launch::async`. Didn't know it.

Comment: @Damon Doesn't `std::launch::async` guarantee this?

Comment: I would make an empty project with some random loop, and first make sure that OpenMP is actually working on your machine. Then take up your  code again, and remove all the calls within the for loop. Add them again one by one and find out where the speedup disappears.

Comment: @freakish: Not sure, but from what I can tell, no (though I might be wrong). The standard has a very twisted non-obvious wording, for example it says _"calls INVOKE (DECAY_COPY (std::forward<F>(f)),
DECAY_COPY (std::forward<Args>(args))...) as if in a new thread of execution"_. Now what does "as if" imply here? In my opinion, it means it could just as well not create a thread, as long as it calls INVOKE(DECAY_COPY(forward(....))) _as if_. It also says that the implementation may choose between behaviors.

Comment: @freakish: The terms are not mutually exclusive AFAIK, but I'm no expert. Please elaborate. The Wikipedia intro states `OpenMP is an implementation of multithreading`